# How Do I Redeem Bitcoin for USD Currency?

Tags: currencies, bitcoin-credit-card

What is the step by step process to redeem Bitcoin into USD Currency & what other options do I have?

Is there a so called prepaid credit card I could redeem it for/into so I can use the cash for purchases, goods, services?

Answer (score 0):

As we know bitcoin as an independent currency is traded in open markets (virtual or physical ones). So, you can sell/buy bitcoins for USD or any other cryptocurrency, fiat currency or even goods and services directly. For example, you can use [localbitcoins.com](http://localbitcoins.com) to trade your bitcoins with people who are willing to pay cash for it. Another example is to use Bitpay Card ([bitpay.com](http://bitpay.com)) allows you to accept bitcoin, store and spend bitcoin securely, or turn bitcoin into USD with the BitPay Card. There are many more.

More importantly, bitcoin is a currency that can be used for purchases directly without the need to convert it into Cash. For example, you can use it to buy goods from [overstock.com](http://overstock.com), [purse.io](http://purse.io), amazon gift cards, etc ...

I hope that helps.